# PubChem service doesn't support looking up compounds given an assay ID?

Tags: chemistry, serviceexecute

Mathematica's [PubChem Service Connection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/PubChem.html) has many requests that return the properties of a compound (or substance). It also provides requests that return all the assays for which a given compound (or substance) has been tested.

But the [PubChem Service Connection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/PubChem.html) does not appear to include requests that return all the compound IDs (CIDs) associated with a given assay ID (AID). This type of functionality is supported by the PubChem [PUG-REST](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug-rest), e.g., :

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/assay/aid/1207599/cids/txt

Looks up all compounds (CIDs) that have been measured with assay AID1207599.

The "CompoundAID" request in Mathematica returns a list of AssayIDs given a CompoundID (or other CID-equivalent specifier) as input.  Similarly, "CompoundAssaySummary" returns a summary given a CompoundID (or equivalent) specifier. But returning the AIDs for a specified CID is not the same as returning the CIDs for a given AID.  Is there an undocumented feature for this?

No: It is not possible to iterate over all CompoundIDs; [PubChem contains >96 million compounds.](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/statistics)

Yes:  I already know I can do it "manually" by

```
URLExecute[
 "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/assay/aid/1207599/cids/txt",
 {}, "CSV"]
```

Rather:  This is a question about the limits and current state of the [PubChem Service Connection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/PubChem.html) implementation in Mathematica 12.

Comment: I can add `"AssayCID"` and `"AssaySID"`, are there any other requests based on assay-id you would want?

Comment: That sounds fine.  

It might also be slick to take advantage of the "post-a-SDF-and-get-the-CIDS" functionality, taking a Molecule as an input.  i"https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/sdf/cids/txt" DM me and we can chat more.

Comment: @JasonB. : Looks like AssayCID is in Mathematica 12.1 (but not documented).  Is there a parameter for the specify the `cids_type=active` option in PUG-REST (like https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/assay/aid/1207599/cids/txt?cids_type=active ) so as to retrieve only active compounds for this assay?  I tried experimenting to no avail with setting "AIDType"->"Active" and "CIDType"->"Active" but without luck (and don't know enough to spelunking the undocumented options)

Comment: ...upon some further spelunking in `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Components/PubChem/Kernel/PubChem.m` it appears that "AssayCID" does have a `CIDType` option, but it only accepts `All|Standardized|Component` here, which are the options for CIDType when looking up CIDs from SIDs, but not for looking for CIDs from AIDs (per the table in https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug-rest$_Toc494865570 ). Is there an easy fix for this? (I want to deploy for a class, so manually editing Mathematica internals is probably not a good solution.)

Comment: Changing the following lines in the `PubChem.m` file fixes the problem
`1268c1268
<     If[!StringMatchQ[ToString["CIDType"/.newparams], "All"|"Active"|"Inactive"],
---
>     If[!StringMatchQ[ToString["CIDType"/.newparams], "All"|"Standardized"|"Component"],
1273c1273
<     params=Append[params,Rule["cids_type",ToString["CIDType"/.newparams]/.{"All"->"all","Active"->"active","Inactive"->"inactive"}]]
---
>     params=Append[params,Rule["cids_type",ToString["CIDType"/.newparams]/.{"All"->"all","Standardized"->"standardized","Component"->"component"}]]`

Comment: I'm sorry this fell off my radar - I will make sure it gets out in the next release. edit: It might be worth your while to file a bug for something like this - go to "Help->Give Feedback".  Then QA will create a ticket, and it will be harder for me to forget about it

Comment: No prob.  Ahead of you on the bug report—I put it into the system along with the diff changes noted above.